# Set Savon global headers value from Initialize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, savon

This is my BaseConsumer module,

```
module BaseConsumer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    extend Savon::Model

  client endpoint: 'my end_point',
         namespace: 'http://abc',
         namespace_identifier: nil,
         env_namespace: 's',
         headers: {}
  end

  def initialize(client_id)
    #I want to set here, client_id in headers value as a global option.
  end
end
```

Now I want to set a value(say, client_id) in global headers. I have tried with `soap_header` but it sets the header value as a local option. I want to set it when I initialize this. It kills my lot of time :( So please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. We can set the headers as a global option easily. Just write the following code in the `initialize` method.... :)

`client.global.headers { options }`